# Use Layer Collection Property Group for UI LIst?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

making a property group for a UI List is not a problem when using Collections, as follows:

```
class CUSTOM_objectCollection(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    coll_ptr: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection)
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CUSTOM_objectCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.custom = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CUSTOM_objectCollection)
```

but trying to use **Layer Collections** by changing type to: `type=bpy.types.LayerCollection` produces `ValueError: bpy_struct "CUSTOM_objectCollection" registration error: coll_ptr could not register`. How can we use Layer Collections instead of Collections?

Comment: Need to be subclasses of  `bpy.types.ID` with some exceptions like bones. Will find ID types are saved in blend eg for the `Collection` in  `bpy.data.collections`  Not for `LayerCollections` which belong to the viewlayer object. The workspace is something to consider looking at.